# Publishing of a modular library to Maven using Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies, publishing, modularity, maven-publish

Suppose I'm using Gradle for a modular library development. In my root project I have subprojects `geometry`, `algorithms`, `visualizer`, and I'd like to publish a jar artifact of each.

As for now in my root `build.gradle` I have the following part:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        publishDemos(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.cg'
            artifactId 'geometry'
            version globalVersion
            artifact project(':geometry').tasks.getByName('jar')
        }
        publishAlgorithms(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.cg'
            artifactId 'algorithms'
            version globalVersion
            artifact project(':algorithms').tasks.getByName('jar')
        }
        publishVisualizer(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.cg'
            artifactId 'visualizer'
            version globalVersion
            artifact project(':visualizer').tasks.getByName('jar')
        }
    }
}
```

My first question: is there a shorter way of describing the publications? For example, I'd like to state that for each subproject I need a publication with the `artifactId` set from its name.

---

Next, my subprojects depend on each other, both `algorithms` and `visualizer` depend on classes from `geometry`, but at this point the jars do not contain the dependencies, and, for example, the user will have to add dependencies to both `geometry` and `algorithms` if they want to use `algorithms`.

So, is there a way for to provide some sort of auto-dependency, so that adding `algorithms` would also add `geometry`? If yes, how do I do it? If no, what is the idiomatic way of providing modular libraries? Should I assemble jars with dependencies instead?

UPD: Am I right that instead of `artifact ...` I should just use `from project(':...').components.java`, because it will pick up both artifacts and dependencies? How do I pick dependencies separately if I use `artifact ...`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do less verbose publication declaration by injecting the same publication config into each subproject. For example for a multi-build project with the structure:

```
ROOT
│   build.gradle
│   settings.gradle
├───subA
│       build.gradle
│
├───subB
│       build.gradle
│
└───subC
        build.gradle
```

In your root `build.gradle`, you can do:

```
apply plugin:'maven-publish'

subprojects{
    publishing {
        publications {
            "$project.name"(MavenPublication) {
                groupId project.group
                artifactId project.name
                version project.version
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each subproject defines its own groupid and version like so:

```
group = 'org.test.sample.A'
version = '1.0'
```

The artifactId is picked up from the subproject name. Running `gradle publish` results in a repo of this structure:

```
org
└───test
    └───sample
        ├───A
        │   └───subA
        │       └───1.0
        │               subA-1.0.jar
        │               subA-1.0.pom
        ├───B
        │   └───subB
        │       └───1.0
        │               subB-1.0.jar
        │               subB-1.0.pom
        └───C
            └───subC
                └───1.0
                        subC-1.0.jar
                        subC-1.0.pom
```

#### Dependencies

This config also automatically takes care of dependencies. For instance if in subproject `subA` you had:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':subB')
}
```

Since I am using `from components.java` instead of `artifact`, the plugin knows to look for dependencies and generates a pom for `subA` that includes:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.gradle.sample.B</groupId>
      <artifactId>subB</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer. Thank you :)

Comment: This works, but produces tasks like `:generatePomFileForFooPublication` instead of `:foo:generatePomFileForMavenPublication`, which I want so that I can do all the publishing with one command. However, if I replace `"$project.name"` with something like `maven`, it complains that `Maven publication 'maven' cannot include multiple components`. Any way to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: @max The answer says ( _I_ wrote the answer, but several years ago, I don't recall the specifics) that running `gradle publish` should do all the publishing in 1 shot, does that not work for you?

Comment: What happens when subprojects have different `from` clauses? Subproject A needs `from components.java` but subproject B needs `from components.web`, which is only available if plugin "war" is applied. How can I do?