# gradle publishing multi module project to AWS Artifact only publishes META-INF

Tags: scala, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory, aws-codebuild

I recently started using gradle and trying to publish a multi module project to [AWS Artifact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-gradle.html). My build file for submodules looks like below

1. Module: core

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:0.4.34"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "net.researchgate.release" version "2.8.0"
}


group "com.local"

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jsonschema2pojo"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "net.researchgate.release"

jar {
    baseName "core-schema"
}

release {
    tagTemplate = 'core-${version}'
}

jsonSchema2Pojo {
    source files("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/json")
    generateBuilders = true
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.0.Final'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.9'
}

afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn uploadArchives
```

2. spark-example

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'java-library'
  id 'scala'
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'scalaStyle'

scalaStyle {
  configLocation = "${project.rootDir}/scalastyle_config.xml"
  includeTestSourceDirectory = true
  source = "src/main/scala"
  testSource = "src/test/scala"
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-core_2.11", version: '2.4.2'
  compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-sql_2.11", version: '2.4.2'
}

configurations {
    runtime.exclude module: 'spark-core_2.11'
    runtime.exclude module: 'spark-sql_2.11'
}

compileScala.dependsOn(scalaStyle)

jar {
  mainClassName = 'NONE'
  baseName "spark-sample"
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
  ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.daemonServer = true
  ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.fork = true
  ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
  ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useCompileDaemon = false
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
  configure(scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions) {
    memoryMaximumSize = '1g'
    jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  }
}
```

And main application build file looks like below:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group "com.local"

subprojects { subproject ->
    configurations {
        deployer
    }

    dependencies {
        deployer 'org.kuali.maven.wagons:maven-s3-wagon:1.2.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "${aws_url}"
            credentials {
                username "aws"
                password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
            }
        }

    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = group
            artifactId = artifactName
            version = version
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${aws_url}"
            credentials {
                username "aws"
                password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now when I run `gradle build` I can see jars getting created for all the modules and root project under corresponding `build/libs/` directory with code files. However when I do `gradle publish` I only see root jar getting published with only `MANIFEST.NF` file as shown below:

[image]

**Update:**

As suggested by @nico I have tried adding the publishing block in `allprojects{}` block but it is publishing each project with the root project name and overriding all of them as seen in below log. I have also tried adding the publishing block in subproject [like mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143514/publishing-of-a-modular-library-to-maven-using-gradle) but still same output.

```
2030009268:spark-store user$ gradle publishAllPublicationsToMavenRepository

> Task :core:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
Multiple publications with coordinates 'com.local:spark-sample:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT' are published to repository 'maven'. The publications will overwrite each other!

> Task :spark-sample:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
Multiple publications with coordinates 'com.local:spark-sample:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT' are published to repository 'maven'. The publications will overwrite each other!
Multiple publications with coordinates 'com.local:spark-sample:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT' are published to repository 'maven'. The publications will overwrite each other!
```

Updated root project build:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group "com.local"

subprojects { subproject ->
    configurations {
        deployer
    }

    dependencies {
        deployer 'org.kuali.maven.wagons:maven-s3-wagon:1.2.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "${aws_url}"
            credentials {
                username "aws"
                password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
            }
        }

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = group
                artifactId = artifactName
                version = version
                from components.java
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "${aws_url}"
                credentials {
                    username "aws"
                    password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your main application build file:

Try including the publishing{} block inside of an allprojects{} block or add it to the above subprojects{} block as well. Currently the publishing-specification is only applied on root-project level.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added the publishing in allprojects block but now it is trying to publish each jar with the parent project name and overriding them one after another.

Comment: I think this refers to the "groupId = group, artifactId = artifactName, version = version" settings. Make sure that for each (sub)project you actually set the artifactName to a unique value and then it should not overwrite the other jars.

Comment: As I just found out the artifactId always defaults to the project name which itself defaults to the folder name where it is located. One way to achieve what you want is to remove the artifactId = artifactName statement and in your settings file do sth. like this: include statement as regular and afterwards changing the project name with project('referenceSameAsInIncludeStatement').name="the name you want your artifact to be published with".

Comment: yeah that artifactnamee was causing the pain.